# .htaccess 301 Redirect Folder and Subfolders

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I would like to redirect a parent folder to a different place than it's subfolders. When I use the code below `/cat1/page_title` redirects to `/new-cat-1/page_title`, instead of `/new-global-cat/page-title`.

```
Redirect 301 /cat1 /new-cat-1
Redirect 301 /cat1/page_title /new-global-cat/page-title
Redirect 301 /cat2 /new-cat-2
Redirect 301 /cat2/page_title /new-global-cat/page-title
```

It appears the redirect for the parent folder is taking precedence over the redirect for the subfolder. I have a long list of redirects under `cat1` and `cat2` that I need to redirect.

**How can I have a redirect that works for both the parent and the sub folders without them interfering with each other?**

Additional info: This is for a Wordpress website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this problem it is better to use `RedirectMatch` here for its regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cat1/?$ /new-cat-1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cat1/page_title/?$ /new-global-cat/page-title
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cat2/?$ /new-cat-2
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cat2/page_title/?$ /new-global-cat/page-title
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed! After using `RedirectMatch 301` for `/cat1/` and `/cat2/`, I was able to just keep `Redirect 301` for `/cat1/page_title/` and `/cat2/page_title/`.